# wait for the previous item in a async loop

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm manipulating a set of files in order as 1 operation can require information of the previous file.

Now I would like to speed up the processing by starting to manipulate the next file before the first has finished.

but I'm having trouble figuring out, a way to start.

```
var infoFromPreviousFile;
foreach (var file in Files) {
  file.Open();

  // Two long-running operations that require to run in order but don't require the previous file
  // Time consuming operation 1 on OpenFile Operation
  var newData = // Time consuming operation 2 on OpenFile Operation

  // One fast running operation that requires the previous file
  // requires information of the previous file
  file.Add(infoFromPreviousFile);

  file.Write();
  infoFromPreviousFile = newData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
    public static void Example<T>(IEnumerable<T> files)
    {
        T SlowOperation1(T item)
        {
            // Do Slow operation1
            return item;
        }

        string SlowOperation2(T item, string previousResult)
        {
            // Do Slow operation2 and return result
            return null;
        }
        var results = files.AsParallel()
            .Select(SlowOperation1)
            .WithPreviousResult<T, string>(SlowOperation2);
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            // Write result
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> WithPreviousResult<T, TU>(this IEnumerable<T> self, Func<T, TU, TU> method)
    {
        TU previous = default;
        using (var iter = self.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (iter.MoveNext())
            {
                previous = method(iter.Current, previous);
                yield return iter.Current;
            }
        }
    }
```

The call to `.AsParallel()` should ensure that `SlowOperation1` is run in parallel, while `WithPreviousResult` will run `SlowOperation2` sequentially. Note that the first item will receive null as the previous value. Replace `string` with whatever type is the result from `SlowOperation2`. All this assumes that `SlowOperation1` is limited by processor time and not IO, otherwise running it in parallel might not help, and might even reduce performance.

Disclaimer: Not tested